# how interpolate variables of haml to coffeescript, what issaved as a class into link_to from haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml

this is my link_to in haml

```
  #actions
    .btn-group
      = link_to report_path(type: 'link', search: params[:search]) ), id: 'download', class: '1_download report-btn' do
      = link_to report_path(type: 'link', search: params[:search]) ), id: 'download', class: '2_download report-btn' do
```

and this is my coffe but don`t works

```
  target_link = switch
    when  $("#report_actions a.1_download") then target_link = $("#report_actions a.1_download")
    when  $("#report_actions a.2_download") then target_link = $("#report_actions a.2_download")
    when  $("#report_actions a.3_download"),  $("#report_actions a.3_download")
      if target_link.length > 0
        init_socket()
```

Comment: Can you post more details from your coffee? Where does `target_link` come from? What values can it take? Try `console.log target_link` to see it. Most probably `target_link` contains string, and of course it will not be equal to a jQuery object.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the error is you are getting and what have you tried so far? For one, you are querying `#report_actions` but the wrapper you have is called `#actions`.